# deleteMany not working with $size operator

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to delete all collections where nested document "nested" has 0 element.

```
 Tag.deleteMany({ "blog": { $size: 0 } }).exec()
```

For some reason, it doesn't work with Mongoose,
but it works when I run it this in Robo

```
db.getCollection('tags').deleteMany({ "blog": { $size: 0 } })
```

Anybody knows why it works in the query shell but not with Mongoose code?
Here's the Schema.

```
var tagSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
tag: String,
created: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
blog: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
         ref: "blog" }]

var blogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
title: String,
image: String,
description: String,
body: String,    
created: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
tag:[{  type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "tag" }]
```

UPDATE... I think it is now Promise chaining issue?

```
 let foundBlog
 Blog.findOne({ title: '1st Post' })            
        .then((blog) => { 
            foundBlog = blog;                
        })
        .then(() => {
            console.log(foundBlog.tag)
            Tag.updateMany(                 
            { _id : { $in: foundBlog.tag} },
            { $pull: { blog: foundBlog._id.toString()} }).exec()                
        })
        .then(() => {
            Tag.deleteMany({ "blog": { $size: 0 } }).exec()
        })
        .then(() => done())
```

For some reason Tag.deleteMany did not work after Tag.updateMany.
Is my promise chain correct? Thanks

Comment: Yes, it is defined.

var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    tag: String,
    nested: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "nested"
        }
    ]

Comment: I tested your mongoose query with a super simple schema and it works as expected. `Author.deleteMany({ "data.books": { $size: 0 } }).exec()` with schema of a `email` as string and `data.books` as an array of another `ref` model called `books`. Just had those handy. Issue is somewhere else. Maybe post your schemas as well?

Comment: I included my actual running code in Question. I narrowed down to a Promise chaining issue... I suspect my chain from Tag.updateMany to Tag.deleteMany is not proper?

Comment: I added console.log before and after each .then() run and the order of execution seems to be correct..... 
UpdateMany End -> DeleteMany Start -> DeleteMany End -> Done called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try chaining this way:

```
let foundBlog
 Blog.findOne({ title: '1st Post' })            
    .then((blog) => { 
        foundBlog = blog;                
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log(foundBlog.tag)
        Tag.updateMany(                 
            { _id : { $in: foundBlog.tag} },
            { $pull: { blog: foundBlog._id.toString()} })
            .then(() => {
                Tag.deleteMany({ "blog": { $size: 0 } }).then(() => done())  
            })           
    })
```

Comment: Yes this solves it. Thanks alot, this really helped me to better understand how promises work.